# Cannot create folder: /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed

Tags: google-chrome, directory

I am trying to disable Google chrome's incognito mode by following the instructions here:

[How to disable Chrome's Incognito Mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116319/how-to-disable-chromes-incognito-mode)

(the first answer)

I am unsure as to how to create the folders needed.
Could someone please give clear, simple, steps as I am a newcomer...
Running: Vanilla Ubuntu 15.10 on an Asus laptop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since, you want an easy explanation to the tutorial you pointed, I am just going to elaborate here:

1. Open terminal from Dash. Type:

   `sudo nautilus`
2. Then, navigate to File System > etc > opt
3. Create a new folder "chrome". Enter the folder.
4. Create a new folder "policies". Enter the folder.
5. Create a new folder "managed". Enter the folder.
6. Now, right-click and Create a new document. Name it: "anyname.json".
7. Exit nautilus.
8. Close the terminal window.
9. Open new terminal window and type:

`sudo gedit /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/anyname.json`

10. Then in gedit, enter:

> {
>
> "IncognitoModeAvailability": 1
>
> }

11. Finally, save the file and exit it. Now, you should be able to get what you needed.

Comment: Glad that I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: first_image]

[image: second_image]

```bsh
sudo -i
cd ../
ls
cd etc/opt
mkdir chrome
ls
cd chrome
ls
mkdir policies
ls
cd policies
ls
mkdir managed
ls
cd managed
ls
subl test_policy.json
```

`subl` is an alias for sublime text. If you have not installed sublime text and set up this alias,
instead of `subl`, one can use

```sh
touch test_policy.json
xdg-open test_policy.json
```

This will create and open the test_policy.json in your default editor.