# How to Permanently disable Private Window option in Firefox Quantum (v.62)

Tags: firefox

I dont want to have Private Browing option available with my Firefox browser. 
I found an extension for v.44, But this is not compatible with Firefox Quantum (v.62) 
https://superuser.com/questions/1044722/how-to-remove-private-browsing-from-firefox-v44

I found a something for Chrome at:
[How to disable Chrome's Incognito Mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116319/how-to-disable-chromes-incognito-mode)

Can I get similar solution for Firefox Quantum??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit dated 20200418**: still valid in Firefox 75

Ensure that Firefox is totally not running

Open a terminal and change directory to `/usr/lib/firefox/distribution`. In case the `distribution` folder does not exist, create it.

Run `sudo touch policies.json`

Run `sudo nano policies.json`

Paste in the following text

```
{
  "policies": {
    "DisablePrivateBrowsing": true
  }
}
```

Save `policies.json`

Now, when you next open Firefox, you won't see the Private Browsing option.

[image: Firefox]

Of course, if someone else has `sudo` access to your machine this exercise maybe pointless. And I don't know if you'll need to do this each and every time Firefox updates.

References:

- [Customizing Firefox Using policies.json](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-policiesjson)
- [mozilla/policy-templates](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md)