# Add a Bookmark icon to Firefox search bar

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I'd like to be able to click on an icon in the Firefox search-bar to immediately bookmark a URL.

I already know that I can click on the <kbd>...</kbd> "Page actions" icon to select the "Bookmark This Page" option, and I know I can drag the URL from the left onto the bookmarks bar to achieve this.

However, is there a way to replace the "Save to pocket" icon and replace it with a "Bookmark" icon?

I am using Firefox 63 on Ubuntu 18.10.

Here is a screenshot of the <kbd>...</kbd> "Page actions" icon icon and the "Save to pocket" icon that I currently have...

[image]

Comment: The picture shows the address-bar, not the search-bar.

Comment: Oh! I only have one entry field; I guess it's a combined search/address bar.

Comment: As said in the main answer, you can add/remove any of the items under the page actions (3-dotted) button, the "Save to Pocket" and "Bookmark This Page" being just two of them. Therefore, removing one is not *needed* in order to have the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's quite simple.

First right-click on the Pocket icon and select '**Remove from Address Bar**'. Then click the '*page actions*' (three dots) icon, right-click on '*Bookmark This Page*', and select '**Add to Address Bar**'.

[image]

You can do the same (i.e. add/remove) with other actions that the 'page actions' list provides.

Answer (score 5):

I'm on Firefox 64 (and you'll be as well once you update).

For Pocket, I have

```
extensions.pocket.enabled;false
```

in my *about:config*.  See https://askubuntu.com/a/1083166/248158 for how to do that (and other stuff) via a policy. Here are my policies:

```
{
  "policies": {
    "DisableFirefoxStudies": true,
    "DisablePocket": true,
    "DisableTelemetry": true,
    "DisableSetDesktopBackground": true
  }
}
```

Now, regarding the bookmarks. If I'm on a page which I haven't already bookmarked, I see a hollow star enclosed in red in the image below:

[image: Page to bookmark]

If the page is already bookmarked, the star is filled. Its color may depend on your gtk3 theme.

If you don't see the star at all, see if https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1203256 helps.

Comment: Right-clicking that star button shows the option to hide it inside the three-dotted button, and *the same is the case for the pocket button* (so no need for changing configs). I guess that was done previously for the star button in OP's case, so the solution is to reverse that action as said in the other answer. The removal of the pocket button makes no sense whatsoever if one avoids the OP's error of  somehow considering that  button as the culprit (a *replacement* of the star button).