# Can I disable Chrome browser's Guest Mode?

Tags: google-chrome

Similar to [disabling Incognito mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116319/how-to-disable-chromes-incognito-mode) to stop users bypassing extensions, is there a way to disable Chrome's Guest Window?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I worked out a solution that is now possible since May 2019 using policies and the same method as disabling Incognito mode.

If you're using chrome, create the folder /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed. (I'm guessing if you're using chromium, create the folder /etc/chromium/policies/managed.)

Then create a file in that directory named test_policy.json. It can have any name you want, but it needs the extension to be .json.

Open it in your favorite editor and put:

{
"BrowserGuestModeEnabled": false
}

(Updated) Source: https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/

Comment: Hi, this solution is brilliant. However, if you can, can you help me to figure out how to do both: disable Incognito+ disable guest mode. I made the son file and wrote {
    "IncognitoModeAvailability": 1, "BrowserGuestModeEnabled": false }.

Comment: However, incognito isn't disabled when I do so.

Comment: Creating separate files with names as test_policy.json and test_policy_1.json doesn't work.

Comment: you can't have any line breaks in the policy file.  So it should look like:
{ "BrowserGuestModeEnabled": false, "IncognitoModeAvailability": 1 }

Comment: It (somehow) worked when I had restarted my computer without making any changes to the json file.

Comment: Look like I lost that setting after updated Chrome.

Comment: @MrPhilby and others, list of available policies moved to: https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/

Comment: Thank you @MrPhilby for answering this question. I was finally able to plug the one loophole of stayfocsd that is the guest mode

Comment: I confirm this works today. Thanks !